# how can I pass data from html to component(angular2)

Tags: html, angular, flask, angular2-template

in my index.html I can print these (keys,name,email)values

```
<body>
    {{keys}}
    {{Name}}
    {{Email}
</body>
<component-app></component-app>
```

these from flask like this

```
return render_template("index.html",keys=my_keys,Name=my_name,Email=my_email)
```

I want to pass keys,name,email data to component-app, What should I do?

or can I pass data from flask to angular2's component??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: no, you can't. But you can create global js variables

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        keys = '{{keys}}'
        Name = '{{Name}}'
        Email = '{{Email}'
    </script>
</body>
```

Then in your component

```
public keys = window['keys']);
```

And in your angular html

```
{{ keys }}
```

Comment: thanks!! it works!
Additionally, i have a question,
Is there a security issue if I send login information like this?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it, cause anyone can access these data with console. In other words if I go to your site and do console.log(window) I will see these data